# Vuex `people[0] = { age: people[0].age + 1 };` won't trigger re-render, why?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, vuejs2, vuex

Please see this minimum example:

Markup

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="$store.commit('changePeople1Works')">changePeople1Works</button>
    <button @click="$store.commit('changePeopleNotWorking')">changePeopleNotWorking</button>
    <pre>
      <code>
        {{$store.state}}
      </code>
    </pre>
  </div>
</template>
```

Vuex

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import App from "./App.vue";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    people: [{ age: 1 }]
  },
  mutations: {
    changePeople1Works(state) {
      let people = state.people;
      people[0].age = people[0].age + 1;
    },
    changePeopleNotWorking(state) {
      let people = state.people;
      people[0] = { age: people[0].age + 1 };
    }
  }
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

[image]

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-sound-fvql7?file=/src/main.js:0-519

I have two *mutation* like this

1. `people[0].age = people[0].age + 1;`
2. `people[0] = { age: people[0].age + 1 };`

`1` work, however, `2` doesn't work, why is this happening?

I know you have to use `push`, `pop`, `sort` to trigger re-render.

And if you mutate the array elements directly, it shouldn't trigger the re-render.

However, the `1` methods works, why?!

`1` methods also directly mutate the array element, it's so confusing.

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

> Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion.

and

> ...it’s possible to add reactive properties to a nested object using the Vue.set(object, propertyName, value) method

and

> Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:

> - When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue

- When you modify the length of the array, e.g. vm.items.length = newLength

But it says nothing about mutating an existing `object[property]`.

- In the first example, an existing object property is being mutated, so it works.  (The `age` property of the first item of the `people` array.)
- In the second example, an array item is being set directly by index, so it doesn't work.  (The `0` index of the `people` array.)

This can seem counter-intuitive because a previously set array index can't be modified by index, but a previously set object property can.

I'm guessing that the reason for this has a lot to do with [`Object.defineProperty`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#How-Changes-Are-Tracked) and Vue's reactivity process.

(Confused me at first, too.)

Answer (score 0):

It's a caveat about Vue.js reactivity.
You should use `Vue.set` if you want to change link to object.
For example it will work:

```
changePeopleNotWorking(state) {
      const newPeople = [...state.people];
      newPeople[0].age = newPeople[0].age + 1;
      Vue.set(state, "people", newPeople);
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-cdn-x90sk?file=/src/main.js

UPD:

From Docs:

> Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:
>
> When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue
>
> When you modify the length of the array, e.g. vm.items.length = newLength

```
var vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    items: ['a', 'b', 'c']
  }
})
vm.items[1] = 'x' // is NOT reactive
vm.items.length = 2 // is NOT reactive
```

So, using an array you cannot change item by index (even existing item), because it's not reactive.

But you can use

```
Vue.set(vm.items, indexOfItem, newValue)
```

For example:

```
Vue.set(state.people, 0, { age: state.people[0}.age + 1} )
```

UPD 2.
`1` and `2` they are not the same. In the first example we don't re-assign array item by link, instead this we change property of observable object. If you look at state in `console.log` you will see, that objects in array (which were initialized) are observable. So, Vue is able to watch changes there.

[image]

Comment: This still does not explain what OP is asking.
`1` and `2` both should not work as per the statements you posted from Vue docs.

`When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`
OP is doing exactly this in `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Properties of plain objects are reactive (defined as getter/setter pair), while array indexes aren't:

[image: reactive array]

This assignment of array element results in non-reactive plain object:

```
people[0] = { age: people[0].age + 1 }
```

This is the limitation of [Vue reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) for arrays:

> Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:
>
> - When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`
> - When you modify the length of the array, e.g. `vm.items.length = newLength`

It can be addressed with `Vue.set` or array `splice`, as the documentation suggests:

```
  Vue.set(people, 0, { age: people[0].age + 1 });
  // or
  people.splice(0, 1, { age: people[0].age + 1 });
```

Or with immutable array, which is acceptable for non-critical places:

```
  let [person, ...people] = state.people;
  state.people = [{ age: person.age + 1}, ...people];
```